# Testing a function that calls a function that returns a promise

Tags: javascript, sinon, chai, chai-as-promised, proxyquire

I have code in the following form:

```
sut.methodtotest = param => {
    return dependency.methodcall(param)
        .then((results) => {
            return results;
        });
};
```

I want to test sut.methodtotest, but when I use chai, mocha, require, sinon and the numerous other frameworks that the Javascript community have at their disposal, I get an error saying:

```
dependency.methodcall(...).then is not a function
```

My question is this: how do I mock dependency.methodcall so that it returns some mocked data and so that the 'then' function is available?

My test code looks like this

```
describe("my module", function() {
    describe("when calling my function", function() {

        var dependency =  require("dependency");

        var sut =  proxyquire("sut", {...});

        sut.methodtotest("");

        it("should pass", function() {

        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `sinon`'s sandbox, like so

```js
var sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
var toTest = require('../src/somemodule');

describe('Some tests', function() {
  //Stub the function before each it block is run
  beforeEach(function() {
    sandbox.stub(toTest, 'someFunction', function() {
      //you can include something in the brackets to resolve a value 
      return Promise.resolve();  
    });
  });
  
  //reset the sandbox after each test
  afterEach(function() {
    sandbox.restore();  
  });
  
  it('should test', function() {
    return toTest.someFunction().then(() => {
      //assert some stuff                                  
    });
  });
});
```

You should `return` assertions in then blocks, e.g. with `chai`:

```
return toTest.someFunction().then((result) => {
    return expect(result).to.equal(expected);                
});
```

Leave a comment if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [jasmine spies](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html) to achieve this:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    //stub dictionary service
    dictionaryService = {
        get: jasmine.createSpy().and.callFake(function() {
            return { then: function(callback) {
                return callback(/*mocked data*/);
            } };
        })
    };
});

it('should call dictionary service to get data', function () {
    expect(dictionaryService.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(/*check mocked data*/);
});
```